# How do I write the paragraph the file as I want in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, file, text

[image][image]

Hello, how can I write the "16. hafta" parts next to "1. hafta" and "17. hafta" parts next to "2. hafta".

```
dosya = open('deneme.txt', 'w')

def rövanslar(array,hafta_numarasi):
    yeni_hafta = swap_cols(array, 0, 1)
    rövans_haftasi=hafta_numarasi+15
    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    for i in range(1, 9):
        dosya.write("%d. hafta %d. maç: %d. Takım vs %d. Takım \n" % (rövans_haftasi, i, yeni_hafta[count, count2], yeni_hafta[count, count2 + 1]))
        count += 1

    dosya.write("\n")

for i in range(1,9):
    dosya.write("%d. hafta %d. maç: %d. Takım vs %d. Takım \n" % (hafta_numarasi, i, hafta1_eslesmeler[count, count2], hafta1_eslesmeler[count, count2 + 1]))
    count += 1

dosya.write("\n")

rövanslar(hafta1_eslesmeler,hafta_numarasi)
```

This is the file operation part of my code. Firstly I am writing "1. hafta" parts. After that I am writing "16. hafta parts but I want to write it next to "1. hafta" parts.

Edit: I use zip method. Here new image. :(

Comment: You need to be more clear about the question. Did you write the above text in file ? Is this a file which you need to read and then write into another file in different order ?

Comment: What does your existing code for writing to the file look like?

Comment: I will edit question now. Sorry.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

- read all the lines that start with 1
- read all the line that start with 16
- zip them together and make strings
- repeat for all other pairings

If you have or make lists of strings

```
a = ['1 abcd1',
     '1 abcd2',
     '1 abcd3']

b = ['16 efgh1',
     '16 efgh2',
     '16 efgh3']
```

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) their lines

```
for lines in zip(a,b):
    new = ' '.join(lines)
    print(new)
```

---

```
>>>
1 abcd1 16 efgh1
1 abcd2 16 efgh2
1 abcd3 16 efgh3
>>>
```

Comment: Can you do it for 1 pair. I don't know very well zip method.